# CodeIgniter 2.1.0 Template Library

Tags: codeigniter

Recently CI 2.1.0 is out.
I have a question. As I recognized that the CI folder structure has been 'evolved' (easy to setup, automatically defines base_url,etc), I'm wondering if the current template libraries like Phil's,william's concept,ocular,etc.. can be adapted to this new CI version.

I've tried Phil's but no luck, I mean..I don't know if I'm missing something this time, and ocular, also, to no avail ( I don't subclass the Controller, as suggested [here](https://github.com/lonnieezell/Ocular-Template-Library/wiki/Installation))

Any better templating suggestions that will be suited enough to the latest CodeIgniter 2.1.0?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting? It's definitely something simple and easily remedied.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. With Ocular, the view cannot be found (it supposed to use both the name of the controller and method to render the view) and returns a blank page (shouldn't be)...

Comment: Ocular in particular looks abandoned (and not very active to begin with). It uses a `MY_Loader` which could be incompatible with CI (just guessing, didn't dig deep). My solution is always to write your own, but try the CI forums if all you're looking for is suggestions.

Comment: Yes, you are right..but, back to the matter at hand, I 'm seeking for some 'fresh' suggestions because I'm done googling something that results in 'familiar' stuff (popular CI template engines,etc..). I'm not good at creating a template library from scratch. Or, do you have any idea on where's the best tutorial to start with?

Comment: See if anything here works for you: http://getsparks.org/packages/browse/latest

Comment: Hey, that opens up a new dimension of template-search..thanks anyway, will try to figure something out from there.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like from the comments above that you're having trouble finding any resources online on the matter. Here's my suggestion for you:

Check the CodeIgniter Change Log [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html), and compare all the changes between this newest release, and the release that you know last worked with the template libraries that you've mentioned above. Use deductive reasoning, and see if you can find a way to modify the templates you need to work with the current CodeIgniter structure. I know that's a lot of work, and is not ideal for your situation. Regardless, it's the best advice I can give at the current moment. Good luck, and happy reading!